# Do something BEFORE unwind segue (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, unwind-segue

I have an unwind segue which goes back to the previous controller and saves an image to the PHAsset library.  The unwind segue works, the saving works, the only issue is that it unwinds before the image saves.  Because of that, the image doesn't get presented on the view controller that was unwinded to, since the view controller was presented BEFORE the picture was saved (it takes a little time for the image to save, whereas it goes back to the view controller very quickly). I was wondering if there was any way to unwind to the previous controller ONLY when AFTER the photo has been saved, not right away.

Here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "savePicture" {

        //Image to be saved
        let newImage = self.appraisalPic.image

        //Store picture to PHAssets
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), {
            PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(newImage)
                let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset)
                albumChangeRequest.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
                }, completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        NSLog("Adding Image to Library -> %@", (success ? "Success":"Error!"))

                //Need code here which doesn't do segue until AFTER picture is saved
                    })
            })

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about "asynchronous".

Comment: Hmmm... I am new to Swift, and not to sure what you mean... Could you clarify please Matt?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)`

will perform everything in the background (until you do something again explicitly on the main queue).

Simply eliminate all `dispatch_async` calls to do all the work on the main thread. If it takes too long, notify the user so he knows there is a short wait until the unwind segue fires.

Comment: Thank you Mundi for clarifying.  If you dont mind, could you eliminate the dispatch_async for me from my code?  I am experimenting around with eliminating the dispatch_async but I am generating a ton of errors.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks again.